# Include a specific version of JQuery and a plugin without conflicting with the page's JavaScript library?

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, bookmarklet, jquery

**TL;DR**: I want to include a specific version of JQuery and a specific JQuery plugin that is associated with my inclusion of jQuery on multiple different sites where I know nothing about the JavaScript libraries/plugins used by them, without conflicts. Possible? How?

**The whole story**: Let's say I want to build a Reddit platform where multiple sites can link to Reddit threads by including `http://myredditplatform.com/reddit.js` and having `<a href="" data-reddit-thread-id="1234"></a>` elements littered on the page. Once a user clicks on a link like that, I open reddit in a beautiful modal window.

Now because I want Reddit Platform experience to be consistent across all sites that use my script, I want all sites to use my particular modal plugin and I want to style the links in my particular fashion.

But I can never be sure what Javascript library or plugins the other sites are using, so I must make sure that when `reddit.js` loads JQuery, it must not conflict with other libraries on the page and when `reddit.js` loads, for example, `prettyPhoto` plugin it should only be associated with the jQuery library included by me.

But I also want widespread adoption for my platform, so I don't want to place any more restrictions on the sites like you must have jQuery, or you must have prettyPhoto loaded. I just want them to include this one JS file, `reddit.js` which does everything for them.

Is it possible to make this work? How would you go about it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Below is a stripped down version of my widget loader which does basically what you want.

The key line of code is `jquery1_8_2 = jQuery.noConflict(true);`

More info here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

```
var myWidgetLoader = function() {

   this.start = function() {
      this.getScript('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js', function(){

         jquery1_8_2 = jQuery.noConflict(true);  // true = unconflict all jQuery vars, including "jQuery"
         (function(jQuery) {
            var $ = jQuery;
            // do stuff that uses jQuery
         })(jquery1_8_2);

      });
   }

   this.getScript = function(url, success) {
      var script = document.createElement('script');
      script.src = url;
      var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0], done=false;
      script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = function(){
         if ( !done && (!this.readyState || this.readyState == 'loaded' || this.readyState == 'complete') ) {
            done = true;
            success();
         }
      };
      head.appendChild(script);
   }

}

myWidgetLoader.start();
```

Comment: Yup, though in the `// do stuff that uses jQuery` area, if I append another script for the plugin, it's not gonna use that jQuery.

Comment: You'll need to modify the plugin code and host it yourself. If the plugin follows standard pattern, that should be trivial. You may find this useful info: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring#Context

Answer (score 4):

You could make a custom build of jQuery that doesn't clobber the globals. Have a look at the source: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/exports.js. You could modify this line:

```
window.jQuery = window.$ = jQuery;
```

to be like this:

```
window.myRedditPluginJquery = jQuery;
```

Then when you run your code, you need to use `myRedditPluginJquery` as `$`. Something like this IIFE:

```
(function($){
    //your code goes here
    //you also probably have to paste the source code for that plugin here too
})(myRedditPluginJquery);
```