# jQuery dependency on asp.net mvc site

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an Asp.NET MVC 4.0 site that uses jQuery 1.11.1. I had an issue where some of the javascript on an end users browser (IE) was not working. For some reason, they had version 1.7.x of jQuery. I've been coding for a long time, but I'm relatively new in the web development area.

Why would the browser not download my copy of jQuery from the server? Is there a way to force the browser to get my version?

Thanks!

Comment: since you mention IE specifically do you know if it work in Chrome or Firefox?

Comment: I don't know if it worked in other browsers. I'm trying to play catch-up from an incident from 2 months ago. So you know how that goes.

Comment: just make sure you delete any older jquery files that might be left over after an update or package upgrade.  bundling usually uses wildcards like `"~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"` that will grab all versions in the directory.

Comment: Can you please provide the code you use to include jquery in your site? @JamieD77 might be on to something IF you are bundling the scripts.

Comment: I'm actually not using wildcards, but referencing the version directly. "                        .Include("~/Scripts/jquery-1.11.1.js")"

Answer (score 1):

If the client is loading your site normally (calling an endpoint on your server) then there is no way they could load any version of jquery other than the one you have included in the script tag on your web page.

If you are doing something fancy like providing a widget that your user embeds in a page then indeed, depending on the order in which the scripts get loaded, the browser might wind up with a different version of jquery.

If you're doing the latter there are methods you can use to get a particular version of jquery for your code. See here for a start:

[Include a specific version of JQuery and a plugin without conflicting with the page's JavaScript library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11491332/include-a-specific-version-of-jquery-and-a-plugin-without-conflicting-with-the-p)

Based on the comments below, you might also have other libraries in your application that also load jquery. The $ variable will get the last version of jquery to load.  I would have thought that every browser would load them in the same order, but perhaps on older copies IE things happen differently (or perhaps there are paths through your app that load things in a different order).

If any of that's true then you'll have to use one of the techniques above.  I'd also look into whether you can force kendo not to take over $.

Comment: I am definitely not doing the widget thing. I'm loading up jquery through asp.net mvc in the bundle.config when the site starts. Optimizations are enabled so I'm relying on asp.net to bundle and minify all my scripts.

Comment: Then if you are serving the same version of jquery to everyone,  Unless maybe you have multiple applications being served from your domain and you are serving multiple versions of jquery from the same url.  One app 1,11 and the other 1.7. Maybe then you might have a caching issue.

Comment: How does it work if I am also referencing the Telerik Kendo UI controls? It appears that they distribute their own version jQuery with their software. I don't reference their version when I'm registering the bundles, just the Kendo.*.js files.

Comment: Are you hosting the jquery file or using a CDN?

Comment: I'm am hosting the jQuery file, not using a CDN.

Comment: Also there is nothing else hosted on that web server other than this site. There are multiple users, each with their own application, but they all use the same set of site pages.

Comment: One other thing, once the end user cleared their browser cache, everything worked normally, and they have not had an issue since.

Comment: Kendo appears to havea minified jquery included in its bundles.  Do the versions match up with what you are seeing?  http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/install/prerequisites